# Jquery MoreThan or LessThan

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a responsive website with a fixed navigation only when the document width is above 769px.

I've got the following code which works fine when i test it using alerts to say whether the window is bigger than the size or lower than the size when re sizing.

However when i add my sticky header script into the else statement it doesn't work and i cant figure out why.

Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Thanks

This is the window size statement:

```
 $(window).resize(function() {
 if ($(window).width() < 769) {
 alert('Less than 769');
 }
 else {
 alert('More than 769');
 }
 });​
```

And this is the code I'm trying to use if the window width is bigger than 769:

```
var aboveHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > aboveHeight) {

        $('nav').addClass('fixed').css('top', '0').next().css('padding-top', '99px');
    } else {

        $('nav').removeClass('fixed').next().css('padding-top', '0');
    }
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just save the state ant test in your scroll event

```
var isRightSize = false;

 $(window).resize(function() {
     if ($(window).width() < 769) {
         isRightSize = false;
     }
     else {
         isRightSize = true;
     }
 });​

var aboveHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function() {

    if(!isRightSize)
        return false;

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > aboveHeight) {

        $('nav').addClass('fixed').css('top', '0').next().css('padding-top', '99px');
    } else {

        $('nav').removeClass('fixed').next().css('padding-top', '0');
    }
});
```

Comment: Just wondering, with the code the way it is now the menu will stick when the page is bigger than a certain size but it will only work if the window is resized. if the page is refreshed the menu will not stick. I've created a jsFiddle to demonstrate the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/zegermens/cPAXn/